# How to remove all P tags from the content?

Tags: wordpress

How to disable automatic wrapping text by a P tag in the text editor? I need the output html be exactly like I wrote in the editor.

**UPD**
I'm using Toolset Types plugin to create WYSIWYG field and display it with a types_render_field function.

Comment: Which text editor are you talking about? Please check your question

Comment: Is this question related to JavaScript? Do you have javascript control over your text editor?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has native function called wpautop which is hooked by default. Remove it and try again:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```